# Write large pandas dataframe as parquet with pyarrow

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I'm trying to write a large pandas dataframe (shape 4247x10)

Nothing special, just using next code:

```
df_base = read_from_google_storage()
df_base.to_parquet(courses.CORE_PATH,
                   engine='pyarrow',
                   compression='gzip',
                   partition_cols=None)
```

I unsuccessfully tried to use different compressions, different partition_cols but fails anyway.

I mentioned It works fine with small dataframes (1000x10<) and it also works when I'm debugging and leave it enough time but in my case I'm getting an error:

```
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Libs I'm using:

```
pandas==0.25.3
pyarrow==0.15.1
```

Comment: Are you able to write or read the same pandas dataframe locally?

Comment: @NibrassHaider Locally it works fine with for **fastparquet** and fails with the same error for **pyarrow**.

Comment: Seems like Google Storage hasn't affect anyhow the error. I reproduced the error locally with pyarrow with another dataset 1500x7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue might be related to this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1345 but I'm not sure.

Here is the workaround I found:

```
from pyarrow import Table
from pyarrow import parquet as pq


df_base = pd.read_csv('big_df.csv')

table = Table.from_pandas(df_base, nthreads=1)
print(table.columns)
print(table.num_rows)
pq.write_table(table, courses.CORE_PATH, compression='GZIP')
```

I'm not sure why exactly it's failing, but setting `nthreads=1` helps to avoid  SIGSEGV (Segmentation error)

Comment: If you have a reproducible example could you please report into the Apache Arrow JIRA or Parquet JIRA? Thank you